# duplicate and not grab

Tags: 3d, blender

In Blender when you duplicate you are automatically placed in grab mode. Is it possible to duplicate and not move the duplicated object? I mean like it would be "clone" or "paste in place" in other vector programs.

Comment: what happens if you press the escape key after duplicating ? does that cancel the grab ? also this is not a programming related question. might want to try [avp](http://avp.stackexchange.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Ok, the space works!. Thank you